# webmatrix 2: how to get intellisense for asp.net forms pages

Tags: webmatrix-2

Posted this as a request on the [WebMatrix uservoice](http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions/suggestions/3117532-support-intellisense-for-asp-net-forms), but maybe I'm overlooking something.
Is it possible to get intellisense working on ASP.NET forms pages?

Answer (score 1):

WebMatrix doesn't support deep c# intellisense for web forms (.aspx pages), you will get basic html intellisense and basic c# intellisense (basically a few default reference assemblies and nothing more).

WebMatrix is intended for light editing of these type of files, for cases where you want to quickly fix an obvious bug/change some text/add a few tags, but not beyond that. You really want to use Visual Studio Web Developer for these types of scenarios.

Comment: Hi Yishai, I think this is a pity. The ASP.NET WebForms web stack is as important as MVC, It is still used a lot (for example in SharePoint), and having webmatrix as a capable editor would be great. Is is possible to add intellisense support myself?

Comment: I agree that it is, and what I mentioned above that is what visual studio is for. You really want the breadth and depth of Visual studio tools for this framework. Unfortunately you cannot extend the editor in WebMatrix (but you can in Visual Studio).

I do see your point and logging a request at webmatrix.uservoice.com is the appropriate way to promote your idea